# Is it possible to let the user edit a R.string?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

Say I have this string

```
R.string.standard_txt
```

is it possible to let the user change that string with something like this:

```
R.string.standard_txt = input.getText();
```

Comment: No. R is a generated file so you can't change it's contents

Comment: No. Use SQLite instead.

Comment: How would it be useful ? `R` is just a set of constants, if the developer does not use these, it has no effect on the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pedro Oliveira said: No. R is a generated file so you can't change it's contents.

Using SQLite instead like @Eng.Fouad suggested solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be possible because R.string.standard_txt is a refrence to String name "standard_txt" and you know R file contains refrences.

you can't asssign text to Reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use of shared preference or constant class with static variable.